# Getting ?? as output of unicode characters while connection Netezza with Python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyodbc, netezza, python-unicode

I am trying to access unicode (Chinese, Japanese, etc) characters in python code from a Netezza database. For the connection, I am using the Netezza odbc driver and sqlalechmy, and a table in netezza which has an nvarchar type column which has chinese characters in it. While accessing that chinese character using python code, the output was ?? instead of actual data.

Table having two columns, one is with datatype id and other is with datatype nvarchar:

```
id(int)  Data(nvarchar)
1        你好
2        你好
3        你好
```

Conection code:

```py
connecting_string="DRIVER={NetezzaSQL};SERVER=hostname;PORT=5480;DATABASE=databaseName;UID=userNamw;PWD=password"
sqlparams = parse.quote_plus(connecting_string)
engine = create_engine(f"netezza+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={sqlparams}")

netezzaConnection = engine.connect()
```

Comment: If you use the connection string to connect via pyodbc directly (instead of via SQLAlchemy) do you get the correct results when you query that column?

Comment: If pyodbc itself works correctly then your issue is with the dialect. The "Known Limitations" section of the [README](https://github.com/IBM/nzalchemy/blob/master/README.md) does mention that "Unicode varchar will fail". You may want to [open an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/IBM/nzalchemy/issues) for this.

Comment: Check it with pyodbc only, getting desired output and performance is also not hindered. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

This was a known limitation when nzalchemy was developed with pyodbc. This is working fine with nzpy dialect of nzalchemy.

```
>>> import sqlalchemy
>>> import nzalchemy
>>> engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("netezza+nzpy://admin:password@localhost:5480/DB1")
>>> conn = engine.connect()
>>> res = conn.execute("select * from t7")
>>> print(res.fetchall())
[('你好',)]
```

Will work on pyodbc.

Comment: Nzpy library gives correct result for above case, but the execution with nzpy library is increased alot. for example -> the execution of fetching 10lac from db is much more in connection using nzpy  as compared using pyodbc or nzalchemy-sqlalchemy for connection.